# PHP - Array inside array dynamically

Tags: php, arrays

Previous, I have searched in Google. But I don't find what I want... 
I want to add 2 array to an array. This is my code :

```
$labelCollection = array();
$labelArray1 = array("Staff ID", "Photo Profile");
$labelArray2 = array("Religion", "Postcode");
```

But, I want to make the result like this :

```
    $labelCollection = 
          array('info_1' => array('Staff ID', 'Photo Profile'),
                'info_2' => array('Religion', 'Postcode')
               );
```

Comment: `$labelCollection['Info_1'] = array('Staff ID', 'Photo Profile');  $labelCollection['Info_2'] = array('Staff ID', 'Photo Profile');`?

Comment: You must answer then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<?php 
$labelCollection = array();
$labelArray1 = array("Staff ID", "Photo Profile");
$labelArray2 = array("Religion", "Postcode");
$labelCollection = array('info_1' => $labelArray1 ,
                         'info_2' => $labelArray2 
                   );
```